# Vue Component Props only available on $vnode

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to the World of Vue.js and I have to build a recursive Component renderer that turns JSON into rendered Vue components.

So far the recursive rendering works just fine, except for the props I'm passing to the createElement function (code below ;) ) is not available as props, but inside the $vnode.data object. 
Any ideas what I'm missing?

The mock JSON I'm using looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": "aslwi2",
  "template": "NavigationBar",
  "data": {},
  "substructure": [
    {
      "_id": "assd2",
      "template": "NavigationBarListItem",
      "data": {
        "title": "NavList Item 1"
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "a2323uk",
      "template": "NavigationBarListItem",
      "data": {
        "title": "NavList Item 2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**My Recursive Rendering Component:**

```
const createComponent = function(node ,h){
    if(!node || !node.template){
        return;
    }

    let children = [];
    if(node.substructure instanceof Array){
        node.substructure.map( async childNode => {
            const childComponent = createComponent(childNode, h);
            children.push(childComponent);
        });
    }

    return h(node.template, {xdata : clone(node.data)}, children.length > 0 ? children : null );
};



export default Vue.component('Structure', {
    render: function(createElement){

        if(!this.structure) return;
        const component =  createComponent(this.structure, createElement, registry);
        console.log(component);
        return component;
    },
    props: {
        structure: {
            type: Object
        }
    }
})
```

**And my dynamically instantiated components:**

```
<!-- Component: NavBar -->
<template>
    <div class="nav-bar">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            data: {
                type: Object
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<!-- Component: NavBarListItem -->
<template>
    <div class="nav-bar-item">
        {{title}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                title : "default"
            }
        },
        created() {
            console.log('list item: ', this)
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Inside the log of the created method in my list item component we find the passed props within the $vnode...**

[image: Props available in $vnode but not as props]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```js
return h(node.template, {xdata : clone(node.data)}, ...
```

I don't know what `xdata` is but it isn't something you should be passing to `h`. The options are documented at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth.

To pass a props you'd use `props`.

```js
return h(node.template, {props : clone(node.data)}, ...
```

While I'm struggling a little to follow the intent behind your code it looks like you may also have a problem with `NavBarListItem` not defining a `title` prop. You can't pass a `title` unless it's defined as a prop. Defining it in `data` isn't the same thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought that the second parameter is the object that will be set as props... Now it works just fine. The setting of title in the data function was just me going crazy and trying around different options :)